# Converting text in to data.frame

Tags: r, text, dataframe

I have several records of the following text data (this is a single record). I want to convert this text into a data.frame. I want to make column headings e.g. LOCUS, DEFINITION, ACCESSION and so on...
What could be the easiest solution to this assignment.

```
LOCUS       KU217831                 477 bp    DNA     linear   BCT 21-JUN-2016
DEFINITION  Candidatus 
            ribosomal RNA gene, partial sequence.
ACCESSION   KU217831
VERSION     KU217831.1  GI:972300480
KEYWORDS    .
SOURCE      Candidatus 
  ORGANISM  Candidatus 
            Bacteria; Planctomycetes; Planctomycetia; Candidatus Brocadiales;
            REFERENCE   1  (bases 1 to 477)
  AUTHORS   Zheng,Y., Jiang,X., Hou,L., Liu,M., Lin,X., Gao,J., Li,X., Yin,G.,
            Yu,C. and Wang,R.
  TITLE     Shifts in the community structure and activity of anaerobic
            ammonium oxidation bacteria along an estuarine salinity gradient:
            Shift in anammox along salinity gradient
  JOURNAL   Biogeosciences (2016) In press
REFERENCE   2  (bases 1 to 477)
  AUTHORS   Zheng,Y. and Hou,L.
  TITLE     Direct Submission
  JOURNAL   Submitted (29-NOV-2015) State Key Laboratory of Estuarine and
            Coastal Research, East China Normal University, North Zhongshan
            Road, Shanghai, Shanghai 200062, China
COMMENT     Sequences were screened for chimeras by the submitter using Qiime
            1.9.0.
```

```
           ##Assembly-Data-START##
           Sequencing Technology :: Sanger dideoxy sequencing
           ##Assembly-Data-END##
```

FEATURES            Location/Qualifiers
    source          1..477
                    /organism="Candidatus Anammoxoglobus propionicus"
                    /mol_type="genomic DNA"
                    /isolation_source="Yangtze Estuary sediment"
                    /db_xref="taxon:363279"
                    /clone="Y4_Winter_53"
                    /country="China"
                    /PCR_primers="fwd_name: amx368f, fwd_seq:
                    ttcgcaatgcccgaaagg, rev_name: amx820r, rev_seq:
                    aaaacccctctacttagtgccc"
    rRNA            <1..>477
                    /product="16S ribosomal RNA"
ORIGIN
        1 ttcgcaatgc ccgaaagggt gacgaagcga cgccgcgtgt gggaagaagg ccttcgggtt
        61 gtaaaccact gtcaggagtt aagaaatata gaaatgttaa tagcattttt atttgactaa
        121 agctccagag gaagccacgg ctaactctgt gccagcagcc gcggtaatac agaggtggca
        181 agcgttgttc ggaattattg ggcgtaaaga gcacgtaggc ggccttgcaa gtcagttgtg
        241 aaatccttcc gcttaacggg agaacggcgg ctgatactac agggctagag tacgggaggg
        301 gagagcggaa cttctggtgg agcggtgaaa tgcgtagata tcagaaggaa cgccggcggc
        361 gaaagcggct ctctggcccg aaactgacgc tgagtgtgcg aaagctaggg gagcaaacgg
        421 gattagatac cccggtagtc ctagccgtaa acgatgggca ctaagtagag gggtttt

Comment: To me, this does not look close enough to any format I recognize (dcf, fwf, yml, ...), not close enough to allow a "slight twist" to make parsing it possible. I may be wrong, but this is likely going to need to be a custom parser for you. Additionally, the data is not perfectly suited for a simple `data.frame`: what structure do you expect from `FEATURES` and `ORIGIN`?

Comment: This is a GenBank file (.gbk) downloaded from NCBI. It's a popular format to represent sequence with metadata.

Comment: Can upload the original file?